# Trying to access BIOS, machine boots too fast to enter it, OS is broken?

Tags: bios

I cannot access BIOS as the computer never shows Logo on boot now.

The system is Lenovo Thinkcentre, I7, 8 gig ram, 2 hard drives run through drive selector.  The system has never seen both drives at the same time.

Drive 1: Multiple Lenox distros
Drive 2: Windows 10
Fast Boot disabled
Legacy boot

Problems first began with Windows 10 about 6 weeks ago. NordVPN won't run no matter what.  Uninstalled, reinstalled, Windows wouldn't allow it to run.  Ran several anti-malware. Still wouldn't run.  About two days later, Windows wouldn't boot.  Tried several system recoveries.  Windows still wouldn't run.  Cloned the drive, then jumped to Drive 1. Linux

Wiped the drive and reinstalled all distros.  All worked fine after each install.
After Fedora installed, and rebooted, all worked fine.

When I rebooted the 2nd time, hoping to make some changes in Fedora, nothing. Suddenly:

1. No Grub, no grub access.
2. No operating system access. Period.
3. Tried drive 2: Windows 10.  Not even recovery
4. Tried BIOS Access function Key.  I must have tried 50 times with hitting the keys to even before power.  No bios access.  F2, F1, F10, Del, Esc, FN Key with all above.  No BIOS Access.
5. Tried booting from USB and DVD.  Of course, it won't boot there unless I can access BIOS.

So, how can I access BIOS without being able to go through keys, operating systems, or USB/DVD Boot?

Comment: Have the machine so it is on (running).  Restart.  Press F1 repeatedly as soon as it is restarting and you should get a BIOS screen. Works on my ThinkCenter.

Comment: @John Every computer has a different key. For HP it is F9 or ESC. for DELL its F2. I've even seen different ThinkCenters with different keys.

Comment: Ye - the Question says Lenovo ThinnkCenter.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10 and up, there are a few mechanics in place to access the BIOS.

1. Use the key that comes with your computer. This will not always work if Fast Boot is enabled in the bios, which appears to be your case.
2. If you start windows normally, you then click start, shutdown, hold shift and then click restart, you will restart the computer into the Windows Diagnostics. From this screen, you can access the UEFI Bios.
3. Start your computer and as soon as windows is about to load, hold the powerbutton for 5 seconds to turn the computer off hard. Your computer should power off as the dots are spinning. Turn the computer back on. Repeat this 3 times and Windows Diagnostics will boot up, allowing you to access the UEFI Bios. This method is a good way in case the computer does not boot. So far 3 failed boots always gives me the Windows diagnostics.